# how to create a range validator using javascript? not use range validator control in VS

Tags: javascript

I want to define a function to validate ranges using java script.
I have two text box that I enter max and min value. here is my piece of code:

```
 <tr id="TR_Max">
  <td><span>max value:</span></td>
  <td><input id="Text2" type="text" style="width:90%"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="TR_Min">
  <td><span>min value:</span></td>
  <td><input id="Text3" type="text" style="width:90%"/></td>
 </tr>
```

I have another text box that users enter their desire value.

```
<input id="user_val" type="text" style="width:90%"/>
```

Now I need to a function that check the users value whether is between max and min value or no. certainly the first I should check the type of the value of max and min. how can I do it?

Comment: They will all be strings. Why do you want one textbox for multiple formats? Isn't the range for a specific purpose?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you even google or this was your first step? can you use HTML5?

Comment: well,how to check the input is between max and min value? for example if user enter a date type. as you say, it considers as a string,

Comment: my purpose is that create a range validator myself

Comment: If you want to convert the string values you get from input fields into numbers you can compare, use `parseInt`/`parseFloat`.

Comment: it's a good way for numbers. how can I do it for other types?

Comment: I would suggest: Create a collection of regular expressions for the different formats you want to handle. Decide an appropriate evaluation order (e.g int, float, date, string) then loop each one until you hit a match. Then you will know your type, ensure both fields match up, then parse them and compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to handle this would be to create a list of regular expressions that can be evaluated in turn. If you find a match then you know your type, if you do not find a match then you can assume it is just a sting type.

The regex list can be paired up with the data type in an array like so:

```
var patterns = [
    [
        'int', /^[\d]+$/],
    [
        'float', /^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/],
    [
        'date', /^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d$/]
];
```

NOTE: the date format must be `dd/mm/yyyy`, but this can be changed as desired

Then assuming the html has a couple of fields (`#min` and `#max`), we can create this function (note the use of JQuery):

```
function compare() {
    var min = $("#min").val();
    var max = $("#max").val();

    if (min === "" || max === "") {
        alert("data missing - check down the sofa");
        return;
    }

    var dataType = "string";

    for (var i = 0; i < patterns.length; i++) {
        if (patterns[i][1].test(min) && patterns[i][2].test(max)) {
            dataType = patterns[i][0];
            break;
        }
    }

    alert("Min and Max are of type: " + dataType);
}
```

It is important to note that both fields must have the same data type, if they do not then it will result in a `string` data type.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/XwdkE/)

---

If you want to then extend that to validate the range, you can do so like this:

```
function checkRange(dataType, min, max) {
    var minValue, maxValue;

    switch (dataType) {
        case 'int':
            {
                minValue = parseInt(min, 10);
                maxValue = parseInt(max, 10);
            }
            break;
        case 'float':
            {
                minValue = parseFloat(min);
                maxValue = parseFloat(max);
            }
            break;
        case 'date':
            {
                minValue = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', min);
                maxValue = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', max);
            }
            break;
        case 'string':
            {
                minValue = min;
                maxValue = max;
            }
            break;
    }

    return minValue <= maxValue;
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/XwdkE/1/) (note: JQuery UI is used to parse the date)